# Improper Integral with infinite lower and upper limit

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I was reading our class notes and found this
[image]

I'm still trying to understand this intuitively. Is there some kind of proof or graphical interpretation for this?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx= \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)dx+ \int_0^\infty f(x)dx$.  If either of the integrals on the right does not exist, the integral on the left cannot exist,

Answer (score 0):

Basically the definition of improper integrals at infinity is (I take $0$ as the other bound, could be any number, WLOG I assume $f$ well behaved in $0$):

- $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{L\to+\infty}\int_0^L f(x)dx$ if this limit exists and is finite.
- $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{L\to-\infty}\int_L^0 f(x)dx$ if this limit exists and is finite.
- $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{\substack{L\to-\infty\\M\to +\infty}}\int_L^M f(x)dx$ if this limit exists and is finite.

Notice that in the double sided integral, we ask for independent $L$ and $M$ limits to exists, considering the symmetrical limit of $\displaystyle \int_{-L}^L f(x)dx$ is a weaker condition known as Cauchy principal value.

Your results are almost direct applications of the very definition of improper integrals.